# I'm creating this simple app using tkinter but the button won't work. I don't know what could be the issue

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk


CENTER=tk.CENTER
NW=tk.NW

root=tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 450, height = 500)
canvas1.pack()

#Function to be called when button is clicked
def getImage(t_entry):
    if(t_entry.get().lower()=="Hello"):          
       photo=tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\Alpha\PycharmProjects\Challenge1\Assets\Image2.jpg")
       canvas1.create_image(225,210, anchor=NW, image=photo)
    elif(t_entry.get().lower()=="My Name is"):
       photo=PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\Alpha\PycharmProjects\Challenge1\Assets\Image1.png")
       canvas1.create_image(225,210, anchor=NW, image=photo)

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Text to Sign Language Interpretation')
label1.place(relx=.5,rely=.5,anchor=CENTER)
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(225, 25, window=label1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Type Your Text:')
label2.place(relx=.5,rely=.5,anchor=CENTER)
label2.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(225, 100, window=label2)

#Entry for user to enter text they want displayed in sign langauage
entry1 = tk.Entry (root)
canvas1.create_window(225, 140, window=entry1)

#Button that Displays Sign Language Image
button1 = tk.Button(text='Show Sign Language', command=getImage(entry1), bg='grey', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(225, 190,anchor=CENTER, window=button1)


root.mainloop()
```

The application displays a sign language image when a user enters text assigned to that image. E.g if the user enters "Hello", it displays an image of "hello" in sign language.

Comment: There are few issues in your code: 1) `command=getImage(entry1)` will execute `getImage()` immediately without clicking the button; 2) `t_entry.get().lower()=="Hello"` will always be `False`, same on `t_entry.get().lower()=="My Name is"`; 3) image will be garbage collected as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function).

Comment: How can I rectify that? Or what would be a better way to do it? I'm new to tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in your code:

1. `command=getImage(entry1)` will execute `getImage()` immediately, not on button click.  Use `command=lambda: getImage(entry1)` instead
2. `t_entry.get().lower()=="Hello"` will always be `False` as the left side is all lowercase, but the right side is not.  Same on `t_entry.get().lower()=="My Name is"`.  Suggest to change the right side to all lowercase as well.
3. image will be garbage collected as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function).  You can make `photo` a global variable to fix it.
4. you have create new image item whenever `getImage()` is executed.  Better create the image item once and update its image inside the function.

Below is the changed code required to fix the above issues:

```py
...
def getImage(t_entry):
    global photo  # avoid garbage collection by using global variable

    if t_entry.get().lower() == "hello": # changed to all lowercase
       photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\Alpha\PycharmProjects\Challenge1\Assets\Image2.jpg")
       canvas1.itemconfigure(image_id, image=photo) # update image item
    elif t_entry.get().lower() == "my name is": # change to all lowercase
       photo = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\Alpha\PycharmProjects\Challenge1\Assets\Image1.png")
       canvas1.itemconfigure(image_id, image=photo) # update image item
    else:
       # clear the image if text cannot be matched to an image
       canvas1.itemconfigure(image_id, image='')

...
# used command=lambda: getImage(entry)
button1 = tk.Button(text='Show Sign Language', command=lambda: getImage(entry1), bg='grey', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(225, 190, anchor=CENTER, window=button1)

# create the image item initially without a image
image_id = canvas1.create_image(225, 210, anchor=NW)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was really helpful and it solved the issue.